# How to place Div in center of page with full page background

Tags: html, css

I want to Align my div with some login info in the center of my page. It works with static values but I want to position it dynamically. Also the background should cover the whole page but it just covers a strip with the height of my div...

Here is my code:

```css
.bold{
 font-weight: bold
}

#login {
 width: 300px;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: outset; <!--Just there to show the border-->

}

.background {
 background-color: #f5f5f0;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class=background> 
 <div class="well well-lg" id="login">
  <h2>LOGIN</h2>
  <form method="post" ng-submit="login()">
   <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username"><br>
   <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Einloggen">
  </form>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For centering the box:

```
.center { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

For maxing the background:

```
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sprazer/g2durrLm/

Answer (score 1):

Check code below.

```css
 
.bold{
 font-weight: bold
}

#login {
 width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
 margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: outset; <!--Just there to show the border-->

}

.background {
 background-color: #f5f5f0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto
}
```

```html
<div class=background> 
 <div class="well well-lg" id="login">
  <h2>LOGIN</h2>
  <form method="post" ng-submit="login()">
   <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username"><br>
   <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Einloggen">
  </form>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.background {
    background-color: #f5f5f0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
}

#login {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ro6frhqp/) of how to implement the centering of the login window inside the background. There is a simply trick to vertically position an element with unknown height in CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.background { background-color: #f5f5f0; height: 100%; position: absolute; width: 100%; }
login {

background-color: white; border-style: outset; margin: 15% auto; width: 300px; }

Comment: @JohnDizzle replace your whole css with this one this will surly sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `margin:auto` in the main `div`.

```
.maindiv{
    margin:auto
}
```

It will do whole `div` in centre.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Instead of applying background to a div, apply it for body tag. Then add `display: inline-block;` to `#login`. Also, add center alignment to `.background` to make login form at center.

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
#login {
  
  background-color: white;
  border-style: outset;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.background {
  background-color: #f5f5f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  <div>
    <div class="well well-lg" id="login">
      <h2>LOGIN</h2>
      <form method="post" ng-submit="login()">
        <input name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username">
        <br>
        <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Einloggen">
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the background div and let the bg color on body (or html). You can set the #login position to `absolute` (affected by scroll) or `fixed` (ignores scroll). The #login top/left calculation is the page width minus half of the object width and the page heigth minus the half of the object height.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

#login {
  height: 130px;
  width: 300px;  
  background-color: gold;
  outline: 2px solid black;  
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
  top: calc(50% - 65px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
}

input {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 2px solid black;  
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: tomato;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="well well-lg" id="login">
<h2>LOGIN</h2>
<form method="post" ng-submit="login()">
<input name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
<input name="password" type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Einloggen">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use background for all html,body like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/6zL44qkx/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f0;
}
```